# Formatar valores PHP

Tags: php

Estou querendo formatar um valor que sai da função `rand()` só que não é do jeito normal. Tenho um `rand()`:

```
<?php
$valor = rand(3000,7000);

echo number_format($valor, 2);
?>
```

> Saída: 5000,00

Eu preciso que a saída seja 50,00 e não 5000,00.

Tinha um código que o `rand()` iria com o "." (ponto), sendo mais ou menos assim

```
<?php
rand(30.00, 70.00)
?>
```

Só que parecia que ele fazia o sorteio com os 2 primeiros valores, de 30 a 70 e preciso também que pegue os centavos, ou seja, pode ser um sorteio que saia por exemplo 41.32

Comment: vc quer inteiros sempre, é isso?

Comment: @MarllonNasser não, preciso tb dos valores depois do "." (ponto). Ou seja, pode ser 30.00 como também 32.59 por exemplo.

Comment: então qual a duvida? rs

Comment: Preciso que a função `rand()` sorteio esse tipo de números. Não só inteiros, mas completos. Tenho o valor minimo 30.00 e o máximo 70.00 então o rand() tem que sortear valores nesse intervalo e quero que retorne tb os centavos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand($min*10, $max*10)/10`

É isso?

```
<?php
echo rand(20*10,30*10)/10
?>
```

Output:

```
25.4
```

Edit:

```
<?php
function randomWithDecimal($min, $max, $decimal = 0) {
  $scale = pow(10, $decimal);
  return mt_rand($min * $scale, $max * $scale) / $scale;
}
echo randomWithDecimal(30, 70, 2);
?>
```

Output:

```
44.37
```

Comment: Não amigo, você ainda não entendeu minha questão rs. Tenho o valor mínimo 30.00 (trinta reais) e máximo 70.00 (setenta reais) com o rand quero sortear um valor entre 30.00 e 70.00, quero que o valor retornado seja tipo 64.23 (sessenta reais e vinte e três centavos). Não quero que ele só me retorne 64.00 e sim o valor inteiro que é 64.23

Comment: Editei..é isso?

Comment: Com certeza! :).. Resolvido!. Você consegue me explicar somente o que você fez com a função `pow` e `mt_rand`?

Comment: Aí é matemática... o `pow` é pra pegar o valor exponencial da quantidade de casas decimais que você quer. o `mt_rand` pode ser substituido por `rand` também. A jogada é pegar o exponencial e trabalhar em cima dele.  ;)